Python Regime Labeling Using Explicit Threshold for Increase/Decrease from peak to trough
I am trying to find the longest stretches of time in a time series where the value from start to end increases by at least a certain threshold without any declines in the interim by at least that threshold. Think of the time series like a stock chart. Suppose the threshold is $50. Find and label the longest stretches of time where the stock goes up by at least $50 without going down by $50 in the interim. Those long stretches are then labeled the "positive regime". Repeat the process for declines of at least $50 without going up by $50 in the interim and label those "negative regime".
Since positive regimes start at troughs and end at peaks, and negative regimes start at peaks and end at troughs, regimes should never overlap.
Below is an illustrated example of Positive and Negative Regimes with a threshold of 2. Note the first peak and trough are in an neutral regime since there is no decline greater than the threshold 2 prior to the start of the first positive regime. The final negative regime, however, should be extended to the -0.80 through though since -0.80 is less than -0.73 (where it currently stops) and there is no increase of at least 2 between the current end and the correct end.
How would you implement this in Python? I have tried using scipy.signal.find_peaks but can't get it to work and I feel like there should be a simpler way I'm missing.

#test.ipynb

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from regimes import plot_regimes, process_time_series

# Sample Data Generation
np.random.seed(0)
time = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
value = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10 * np.pi, 100)) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': time, 'Value': value})

# Process the time series data
df_extrema, regimes_df, final_regimes_df = process_time_series(df, value_column='Value', threshold=2, time_column='Time')

# Plot the final regimes along with peaks and troughs
plot_regimes(df, df_extrema, final_regimes_df, value_column='Value', time_column='Time')

# regimes.py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

def find_extrema(df, time_column='Time', value_column='Value'):
    """
    Identifies peaks and troughs in the given time series data.
    
    Parameters:
    - df (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame containing time and value columns.
    - time_column (str): Name of the column containing the time data.
    - value_column (str): Name of the column containing the time series values.
    
    Returns:
    - df_extrema (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame with extrema points and their types.
    """
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(df[value_column])
    troughs, _ = find_peaks(-df[value_column])
    
    extrema_indices = list(peaks) + list(troughs)
    extrema_types = ['Peak'] * len(peaks) + ['Trough'] * len(troughs)
    
    # Include first and last points as extrema
    if 0 not in extrema_indices:
        first_val = df.iloc[0][value_column]
        second_val = df.iloc[1][value_column]
        extrema_indices.append(0)
        extrema_types.append('Peak' if first_val > second_val else 'Trough')
    
    last_idx = len(df) - 1
    if last_idx not in extrema_indices:
        last_val = df.iloc[last_idx][value_column]
        second_last_val = df.iloc[last_idx - 1][value_column]
        extrema_indices.append(last_idx)
        extrema_types.append('Peak' if last_val > second_last_val else 'Trough')
    
    # Create the extrema DataFrame
    extrema = sorted(extrema_indices)
    sorted_extrema_types = [extrema_types[extrema_indices.index(idx)] for idx in extrema]
    df_extrema = df.iloc[extrema].copy().reset_index(drop=True)
    df_extrema['Type'] = sorted_extrema_types
    
    return df_extrema

def label_regimes(df_extrema, threshold=0.25, value_column='Value', time_column='Time'):
    """
    Labels regimes based on transitions between extrema points.
    
    Parameters:
    - df_extrema (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame containing extrema points and types.
    - threshold (float): Minimum height change to consider as a regime.
    - value_column (str): Column name for time series values.
    - time_column (str): Column name for time values.
    
    Returns:
    - regimes_df (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame containing labeled regimes.
    """
    regimes = []
    for i in range(len(df_extrema) - 1):
        current = df_extrema.iloc[i]
        next_ = df_extrema.iloc[i + 1]
        height_change = next_[value_column] - current[value_column]
        
        if abs(height_change) >= threshold:
            regime_type = 'Positive' if current['Type'] == 'Trough' and next_['Type'] == 'Peak' else 'Negative'
            regimes.append({
                'Start_Time': current[time_column],
                'End_Time': next_[time_column],
                'Start_Type': current['Type'],
                'End_Type': next_['Type'],
                'Height_Change': height_change if regime_type == 'Positive' else -height_change,
                'Regime_Type': regime_type
            })
    
    return pd.DataFrame(regimes)

def merge_consecutive_regimes(regimes_df, df, time_column='Time', value_column='Value'):
    """
    Merges consecutive regimes of the same type.
    """
    if regimes_df.empty:
        return regimes_df.copy()
    
    merged_regimes = []
    current_regime = regimes_df.iloc[0].copy()
    
    for i in range(1, len(regimes_df)):
        next_regime = regimes_df.iloc[i]
        
        if next_regime['Regime_Type'] == current_regime['Regime_Type']:
            current_regime['End_Time'] = next_regime['End_Time']
            current_regime['End_Type'] = next_regime['End_Type']
            start_value = df.loc[df[time_column] == current_regime['Start_Time'], value_column].values[0]
            end_value = df.loc[df[time_column] == current_regime['End_Time'], value_column].values[0]
            
            current_regime['Height_Change'] = (
                end_value - start_value if current_regime['Regime_Type'] == 'Positive' else start_value - end_value
            )
        else:
            merged_regimes.append(current_regime)
            current_regime = next_regime.copy()
    
    merged_regimes.append(current_regime)
    return pd.DataFrame(merged_regimes).reset_index(drop=True)

def calculate_whitespace(merged_regimes_df, df, time_column='Time', value_column='Value'):
    """
    Identifies gaps between merged regimes as whitespace.
    """
    whitespace = []
    for i in range(len(merged_regimes_df) - 1):
        current_regime = merged_regimes_df.iloc[i]
        next_regime = merged_regimes_df.iloc[i + 1]
        
        current_end_time = current_regime['End_Time']
        next_start_time = next_regime['Start_Time']
        
        if next_start_time > current_end_time:
            current_end_value = df.loc[df[time_column] == current_end_time, value_column].values[0]
            next_start_value = df.loc[df[time_column] == next_start_time, value_column].values[0]
            whitespace_type = 'Positive' if current_end_value < next_start_value else 'Negative'
            
            whitespace.append({
                'Start_Time': current_end_time,
                'End_Time': next_start_time,
                'Start_Height': current_end_value,
                'End_Height': next_start_value,
                'Whitespace_Type': whitespace_type
            })
    
    return pd.DataFrame(whitespace)

def add_whitespace_as_regimes_and_merge(merged_regimes_df, whitespace_df, df, time_column='Time', value_column='Value'):
    """
    Adds whitespace as new regimes and merges consecutive regimes of the same type.
    """
    if whitespace_df.empty:
        return merged_regimes_df.copy()
    
    whitespace_regimes = []
    for _, ws in whitespace_df.iterrows():
        start_time = ws['Start_Time']
        end_time = ws['End_Time']
        whitespace_type = ws['Whitespace_Type']
        start_type = 'Trough' if whitespace_type == 'Positive' else 'Peak'
        end_type = 'Peak' if whitespace_type == 'Positive' else 'Trough'
        height_change = ws['End_Height'] - ws['Start_Height'] if whitespace_type == 'Positive' else ws['Start_Height'] - ws['End_Height']
        
        whitespace_regimes.append({
            'Start_Time': start_time,
            'End_Time': end_time,
            'Start_Type': start_type,
            'End_Type': end_type,
            'Height_Change': height_change,
            'Regime_Type': whitespace_type
        })
    
    whitespace_regimes_df = pd.DataFrame(whitespace_regimes)
    combined_regimes = pd.concat([merged_regimes_df, whitespace_regimes_df], ignore_index=True)
    combined_regimes = combined_regimes.sort_values(by='Start_Time').reset_index(drop=True)
    
    return merge_consecutive_regimes(combined_regimes, df, time_column, value_column)

def process_time_series(df, time_column='Time', value_column='Value', threshold=0.25):
    """
    Processes the time series data to identify, merge, and label regimes.
    
    Parameters:
    - df (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame containing time and value data.
    - time_column (str): Column name for time data.
    - value_column (str): Column name for time series values.
    - threshold (float): Height change threshold to identify significant regimes.
    
    Returns:
    - df_extrema (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame of identified peaks and troughs.
    - regimes_df (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame of initially labeled regimes.
    - final_regimes_df (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame of final labeled regimes.
    """
    if time_column not in df.columns or value_column not in df.columns:
        raise ValueError(f"DataFrame must contain '{time_column}' and '{value_column}' columns.")
    
    df = df.sort_values(by=time_column).reset_index(drop=True)
    df_extrema = find_extrema(df, time_column, value_column)
    regimes_df = label_regimes(df_extrema, threshold, value_column, time_column)
    merged_regimes_df = merge_consecutive_regimes(regimes_df, df, time_column, value_column)
    whitespace_df = calculate_whitespace(merged_regimes_df, df, time_column, value_column)
    final_regimes_df = add_whitespace_as_regimes_and_merge(merged_regimes_df, whitespace_df, df, time_column, value_column)
    
    return df_extrema, regimes_df, final_regimes_df

def plot_regimes(df, df_extrema, final_regimes_df, value_column='Value', time_column='Time'):
    """
    Plots the time series with shaded regimes, highlighting peaks and troughs and labeling their heights.
    
    Parameters:
    - df (pd.DataFrame): Original time series data.
    - df_extrema (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame with identified peaks and troughs.
    - final_regimes_df (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame containing the final regimes.
    - value_column (str): Column name for time series values.
    - time_column (str): Column name for time.
    
    Returns:
    - None: Displays the plot.
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
    plt.plot(df[time_column], df[value_column], label=value_column, color='blue')
    
    # Plot peaks and troughs
    peaks = df_extrema[df_extrema['Type'] == 'Peak']
    troughs = df_extrema[df_extrema['Type'] == 'Trough']
    
    plt.plot(peaks[time_column], peaks[value_column], 'r^', markersize=10, label='Peaks')
    plt.plot(troughs[time_column], troughs[value_column], 'gv', markersize=10, label='Troughs')
    
    # Annotate peak and trough heights
    for _, row in peaks.iterrows():
        plt.text(row[time_column], row[value_column], f"{row[value_column]:.2f}", 
                 fontsize=9, color='red', ha='center', va='bottom')
    
    for _, row in troughs.iterrows():
        plt.text(row[time_column], row[value_column], f"{row[value_column]:.2f}", 
                 fontsize=9, color='green', ha='center', va='top')
    
    # Define colors for regimes
    color_map = {'Positive': 'green', 'Negative': 'orange'}
    
    # Shade final regimes
    for _, regime in final_regimes_df.iterrows():
        plt.axvspan(regime['Start_Time'], regime['End_Time'],
                    color=color_map[regime['Regime_Type']], alpha=0.3)
    
    # Create custom legend for shaded regimes
    positive_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', alpha=0.3, label='Positive Regime')
    negative_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='orange', alpha=0.3, label='Negative Regime')
    
    # Combine all legends
    plt.legend(handles=[
        plt.Line2D([], [], color='blue', label=value_column),
        plt.Line2D([], [], marker='^', color='r', linestyle='None', markersize=10, label='Peaks'),
        plt.Line2D([], [], marker='v', color='g', linestyle='None', markersize=10, label='Troughs'),
        positive_patch,
        negative_patch
    ], loc='upper right')
    
    # Enhance plot
    plt.title('Time Series with Shaded Positive and Negative Regimes')
    plt.xlabel(time_column)
    plt.ylabel(value_column)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


Are you sure that your assumptions "regimes should never overlap", "positive regimes start at troughs and end at peaks", and "negative regimes start at peaks and end at troughs" are correct? Take [1, 10, 11, 0] and a threshold of 10. Isn't the longest positive regime going from 1 to 11, and the longest negative regime going from 10 to 0, according to your definitions of positive and negative regimes? If so, then the regimes do overlap, and the negative regime doesn't start at a peak. If not, please let me know where I got your definitions wrong.

The positive regime would be 1->10->11. 10->0 would not be a negative regime since it does not start at a peak (11 is the peak not 10). 11->0 is a downward move greater than the threshold 10 and starts at a local peak, so the negative regime would be from 11->0.

Thank you for your answer. Your current definition of a negative regime simply says "declines of at least X without going up by X in the interim". This is true for 10→11→0 with a threshold of 10 (decline of exactly 10, no going up by 10 in the interim). Given your answer, am I correct that this definition should be extended as follows: "Starting from a peak, declines of at least X without going up by X in the interim" (and likewise for positive regimes)? I am insisting, because there cannot be a clear answer without a clear definition.

Two more questions: What would be the positive and negative regime in (1) [0, 10, 9, 10, 0] and (2) [0, 10, 10, 0], again assuming a threshold of 10?

(1) 0->10->9->10 would be positive regime since increased by at least threshold 10 without a decline of at least 10. 10->0 would be the negative regime since decline of 10. (2) 0 ->10 -> 10 would be the positive regime. 10->0 would be the negative regime

I think there is an approach where you iterate over each point in the graph, check the change since the last peak/trough, update the most recent peak/most recent trough if the current point is higher/lower than the previous and then store the end of the previous regime. Need to think more about it.

Thanks again for clarifying. I asked for case 1 because as you may have noticed the example is symmetric. I also thought the definitions of positive and negative regime would be symmetric. However, given your answer, the definition of a negative regime will only use what's left once the positive regimes have been defined (otherwise, again, 10→9→10→0 should be a negative regime in my opinion). That seems to be a crucial detail to me.

Gotcha. I see the other approach and both seem equally valid. I wouldn't define it as favoring positive regimes first over negative regimes though, I think it is favoring the regimes that come first over the regimes that start later.

Would that give you the expected result? The code is not very polished, I hope this is understandable!
The idea is similar to yours I think. First it computes the difference between extremas (deltas) and then assess where it is below (negative_regime_change) or over your threshold (positive_regime_change). Then, it does a comparison with the current regime (current_regime).
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

# Const
TRESHOLD=2

# Sample Data Generation
np.random.seed(0)
time = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
value = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10 * np.pi, 100)) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)

# Find peaks and troughs
peaks, _ = find_peaks(value)
troughs, _ = find_peaks(-value)
extremas = np.sort(np.concatenate([peaks, troughs]))
# Add first and last values if necessary
if 0 not in extremas: extremas = np.concatenate([[0], extremas])
if (last:=(len(time)-1)) not in extremas: extremas = np.concatenate([extremas, [last]])

# Diff between extremas
deltas = np.diff(value[extremas])

# Check when a change of regime happen
positive_regime_change = deltas >= TRESHOLD    
negative_regime_change = deltas <= -TRESHOLD     
    
# Start regime
if positive_regime_change[0]:
    current_regime = "positive"
elif negative_regime_change[0]:
    current_regime = "negative"
else:
    current_regime = "neutral"

regimes = []

i = 0

for j in range(len(deltas)):
    
    if positive_regime_change[j]:
        if current_regime != "positive":
            regimes.append([extremas[i], extremas[j], current_regime])
            current_regime = "positive"
            i = j
    
    elif negative_regime_change[j]:
        if current_regime != "negative":
            regimes.append([extremas[i], extremas[j], current_regime])
            current_regime = "negative"
            i = j

regimes.append([extremas[i], extremas[j]+1, current_regime])

print(regimes)



If I understand you correctly then this find_regimes function indentifies stretches time where the stock goes up or down by at least the threshold without reverting by the same threshold in the opposite direction. Let me know if this is what your looking for:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

def find_extrema(df, time_column='Time', value_column='Value'):
    """
    Identifies peaks and troughs in the given time series data.
    """
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(df[value_column])
    troughs, _ = find_peaks(-df[value_column])
    
    extrema_indices = list(peaks) + list(troughs)
    extrema_types = ['Peak'] * len(peaks) + ['Trough'] * len(troughs)
    
    # Include first and last points as extrema
    if 0 not in extrema_indices:
        first_val = df.iloc[0][value_column]
        second_val = df.iloc[1][value_column]
        extrema_indices.append(0)
        extrema_types.append('Peak' if first_val > second_val else 'Trough')
    
    last_idx = len(df) - 1
    if last_idx not in extrema_indices:
        last_val = df.iloc[last_idx][value_column]
        second_last_val = df.iloc[last_idx - 1][value_column]
        extrema_indices.append(last_idx)
        extrema_types.append('Peak' if last_val > second_last_val else 'Trough')
    
    extrema = sorted(extrema_indices)
    sorted_extrema_types = [extrema_types[extrema_indices.index(idx)] for idx in extrema]
    df_extrema = df.iloc[extrema].copy().reset_index(drop=True)
    df_extrema['Type'] = sorted_extrema_types
    
    return df_extrema

def find_regimes(df, value_column='Value', time_column='Time', threshold=50):
    """
    Identify positive and negative regimes in the time series based on the threshold.
    """
    regimes = []
    start_idx = 0
    current_regime = None
    start_value = df.loc[start_idx, value_column]
    
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        current_value = df.loc[i, value_column]
        change = current_value - start_value

        if current_regime is None:
            # Determine initial regime based on the first significant change
            if change >= threshold:
                current_regime = 'Positive'
            elif change <= -threshold:
                current_regime = 'Negative'
            if current_regime:
                start_idx = i - 1

        if current_regime == 'Positive' and change < -threshold:
            # Positive regime ends, a negative regime may begin
            regimes.append({
                'Start_Time': df.loc[start_idx, time_column],
                'End_Time': df.loc[i - 1, time_column],
                'Regime_Type': current_regime
            })
            current_regime = None
            start_value = df.loc[i, value_column]
        
        elif current_regime == 'Negative' and change > threshold:
            # Negative regime ends, a positive regime may begin
            regimes.append({
                'Start_Time': df.loc[start_idx, time_column],
                'End_Time': df.loc[i - 1, time_column],
                'Regime_Type': current_regime
            })
            current_regime = None
            start_value = df.loc[i, value_column]
    
    # Append the last regime if it was still ongoing
    if current_regime:
        regimes.append({
            'Start_Time': df.loc[start_idx, time_column],
            'End_Time': df.loc[len(df) - 1, time_column],
            'Regime_Type': current_regime
        })
    
    return pd.DataFrame(regimes)

def plot_regimes(df, df_extrema, final_regimes_df, value_column='Value', time_column='Time'):
    """
    Plots the time series with shaded regimes, highlighting peaks and troughs and labeling their heights.
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
    plt.plot(df[time_column], df[value_column], label=value_column, color='blue')
    
    # Plot peaks and troughs
    peaks = df_extrema[df_extrema['Type'] == 'Peak']
    troughs = df_extrema[df_extrema['Type'] == 'Trough']
    
    plt.plot(peaks[time_column], peaks[value_column], 'r^', markersize=10, label='Peaks')
    plt.plot(troughs[time_column], troughs[value_column], 'gv', markersize=10, label='Troughs')
    
    # Annotate peak and trough heights
    for _, row in peaks.iterrows():
        plt.text(row[time_column], row[value_column], f"{row[value_column]:.2f}", 
                 fontsize=9, color='red', ha='center', va='bottom')
    
    for _, row in troughs.iterrows():
        plt.text(row[time_column], row[value_column], f"{row[value_column]:.2f}", 
                 fontsize=9, color='green', ha='center', va='top')
    
    # Define colors for regimes
    color_map = {'Positive': 'green', 'Negative': 'orange'}
    
    # Shade final regimes
    for _, regime in final_regimes_df.iterrows():
        plt.axvspan(regime['Start_Time'], regime['End_Time'],
                    color=color_map[regime['Regime_Type']], alpha=0.3)
    
    # Create custom legend for shaded regimes
    positive_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', alpha=0.3, label='Positive Regime')
    negative_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='orange', alpha=0.3, label='Negative Regime')
    
    plt.legend(handles=[
        plt.Line2D([], [], color='blue', label=value_column),
        plt.Line2D([], [], marker='^', color='r', linestyle='None', markersize=10, label='Peaks'),
        plt.Line2D([], [], marker='v', color='g', linestyle='None', markersize=10, label='Troughs'),
        positive_patch,
        negative_patch
    ], loc='upper right')
    
    plt.title('Time Series with Shaded Positive and Negative Regimes')
    plt.xlabel(time_column)
    plt.ylabel(value_column)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# Sample Data Generation
np.random.seed(0)
time = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
value = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10 * np.pi, 100)) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': time, 'Value': value})

# Apply the regime detection
threshold = 2  # Set your threshold
df_extrema = find_extrema(df, value_column='Value')
regimes_df = find_regimes(df, value_column='Value', threshold=threshold)

# Plot the final regimes along with peaks and troughs
plot_regimes(df, df_extrema, regimes_df, value_column='Value')


Hi this code just appears to provide 1 large negative regime as the label but there are clear moves of at least +2 and -2 (the threshold) in the data. See the picture I provided

I really think I can provide a canonical answer for this, but I don't quite understand your thresholds, what are you looking for exactly and I appreciate your patience!

Can you elaborate on what you are asking? Between the question, the example graph provided and the comments to the original question not sure what is unclear.
